# Можно ли улучшить мой код?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-api

Здравствуйте возможно ли улучшить  данный код?
под словом улучшить я говорю о :читабельности, модульности, производительности. В фронте не силен,только чистый js,сам код:

```
const inviteRegex = () => {
  const protocol = '(?:(?:http|https)://)?';
  const subdomain = '(?:www.)?';
  const domain = '(?:disco|discord|discordapp).(?:com|gg|io|li|me|net|org)';
  const path = '(?:/(?:invite))?/([a-z0-9-.]+)';

  const regex = `(${protocol}${subdomain}(${domain}${path}))`;

  return new RegExp(regex, 'i');
};

async function inviteCheck(bot, message) {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') && message.channel.permissionsFor(bot.user.id).has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
    const check = inviteRegex().text(message.content);
    if (check) {
      const invites = '';
      const fetchInvite = await bot.fetchInvite(message.content).catch(null);
      if (fetchInvite.guild.id === message.guild.id) return false;

      if (message.channel.permissionsFor(bot.user.id).has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
        await message.delete().catch(null);
      }

      message.channel.send(`${fetchInvite.guild.name}(\`${fetchInvite.guild.id}\`) ОТ ${message.author}(\`${message.author.id}\`)`);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: `const check = inviteRegex().text(message.content);` - о, кажется ошибка. Должно быть `test` ?

Comment: Ой,случайно описался,но всё же,можно ли как-то улучшить производительность?

Comment: так как функция `inviteRegex` не параметризована её вообще незачем вызывать для *каждого* полученного сообщения, достаточно хранить её результат в константе

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: @KristalkillPlay Думал примерно так же, как  nörbörnën ) Вон с теми return true, return false в самом конце достаточно трудно понять, в каких случаях и что происхдит. Если в коде должно быть такое, первым делом прописываю обратные условия сразу c return - чтобы обработать все ненужные случаи и больше про них не думать - уже записать основной код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно немного улучшить стилистически, чтобы код был более читабельным

```
const inviteRegex = (() => {
  const protocol = '(?:(?:http|https)://)?';
  const subdomain = '(?:www.)?';
  const domain = '(?:disco|discord|discordapp).(?:com|gg|io|li|me|net|org)';
  const path = '(?:/(?:invite))?/([a-z0-9-.]+)';

  return new RegExp(`(${protocol}${subdomain}(${domain}${path}))`, 'i');
})();

async function inviteCheck(bot, message) {
  const isMemberAdministrator = message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR');
  const isBootManage = message.channel.permissionsFor(bot.user.id).has('MANAGE_MESSAGES');

  if (!isMemberAdministrator && isBootManage && inviteRegex.test(message.content)) {

      const fetchInvite = await bot.fetchInvite(message.content).catch(null);

      if (fetchInvite && fetchInvite.guild.id !== message.guild.id) {

        if (isBootManage) {
          await message.delete().catch(null);
        }

        message.channel.send(`${fetchInvite.guild.name}(\`${fetchInvite.guild.id}\`) ОТ ${message.author}(\`${message.author.id}\`)`);

        return true;
      }

  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: можно было первый `if` в `inviteCheck` сразу поставить на `return false;` и не плодить вложенность.